# WP7 Binding a checkbox IsChecked to an sql database bit C#

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to bind a checkboxs IsChecked property to a bit value stored in an sql database as Underlay.

The data context for the page is a room object, pulled strait from the db, which contains the stored bit.

```
newPiv.DataContext = viewModel.db.Rooms.SingleOrDefault(r => r.RoomId == roomNumber);
```

xaml code

```
<CheckBox x:Name="underlayCB" IsChecked="{Binding Underlay, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

database:

```
private System.Nullable<bool> _Underlay;
partial void OnUnderlayChanging(System.Nullable<bool> value);
partial void OnUnderlayChanged();
[Column(Storage = "_Underlay", DbType = "Bit")]
    public System.Nullable<bool> Underlay
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Underlay;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Underlay != value))
            {
                this.OnUnderlayChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Underlay = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Underlay");
                this.OnUnderlayChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have several other bindings on the same page and other pages within the app which all work, could someone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Looks like a nullable bool to me, not a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the `Binding`'s `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit`, this requires you to call `Binding.UpdateSource()` does one the methods your setter calls do that? Why not just leave it as `Default` or `PropertyChanged`?

Is `INotifyPropertyChanged`'s event raised?

Incidentally instead of

```
private System.Nullable<bool> _Underlay;
```

You can have:

```
private bool? _Underlay;
```

Comment: What did you try? have you monitored the Debug window while debugging for binding errors?

Comment: ok by changing the bindings UpdateSourceTrigger back to default and changing the database entry to NOT NULL I have the binding working but if it is changed more than three times it crashes the app

Comment: I do not know why you changed it to NOT NULL, The crash is another issue, look for the exception and follow the stack trace